# URL Rewrite issue - category/sub-category/product urls not working

Tags: magento2, url

URL Rewrite issue - category/sub-category/product urls not working.

When I create a new product it does not create the pretty urls, instead it defaults to the system urls. Could it be because they could be in a competing parent category structure when created?

Example:

If I'm selling flip flops and upon creation I put them in competing categories would that cause confusion and would it just default to the system URL?

mywebsite.com/products/clothing/accessories/shoes/flipflops.html

mywebsite.com/specials/shoe-specials/flipflops.html

Answer (score 0):

@matthew, using the Magento 2 sample data. I created the following.

http://testsite.com/sale/push-it-messenger-bag.html

http://testsite.com/push-it-messenger-bag.html

Did you try running `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

From a Magento confusion standpoint, you shouldn't have any issues as long as you have Canonical Links for Products enabled.  Since you now have two URL paths' for the same content;

`<link  rel="canonical" href="http://testsite.com/push-it-messenger-bag.html" />`

I'm also making the assumption that you have the `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` set to `yes` in when you tried?

What specific version of Magento are you on?

Comment: Version 2.1.9.  I reindexed  but I did not see a change.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan, I looked through the release notes of later releases of Magento and I didn't see anything specific to this issue.  However, maybe its a version of Magento issue?    I tested this using 2.2.2 stock Magento with sample data and it works as expected.  Can you go to mywebsite.com/flipflops.html and get to your product?